# How can I set session never expire in django

Tags: python, django, session, timeout

I am using Django-Python. Is there any way to set session never expire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about infinite sessions, but if you use your session middleware
and use a huge AUTOLOGOUT time, it will work.

does 100 years sound ok?

on settings.py

```
# time in minutes
# 60min*24hours*365days*100years
AUTO_LOGOUT = 52560000
```

Create a middleware and add it to settings.py in the middleware section

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import auth
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class AutoLogout:

    def process_request(self, request):

        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            # Can't log out if is not logged in
            return
        try:
            # last click
            last_touch = datetime.strptime(request.session['last_touch'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            # getting auto logout time
            auto_logout_time = settings.AUTO_LOGOUT

            try:
                if datetime.now() - last_touch > timedelta(0, auto_logout_time * 60, 0):
                    del request.session['last_touch']
                    auth.logout(request)
                    request.session['warning'] = unicode(_("You have been logged out"))
                    return
            except Exception as e:
                # It should not reach this point
                auth.logout(request)
                del request.session['last_touch']
                request.session['warning'] = unicode(_("You have been logged out"))

        except KeyError:
            pass

         request.session['last_touch'] = str(datetime.now())
```

Comment: I'll use the default timeout, 2 weeks. Thanks anyway.

Comment: 52560000s == 1.67 years
I think you forgot a factor of 60.

Comment: @yspreen the AUTOLOGOUT is in minutes. So if you want to logout after 30 minutes of inactivity you simple type 30 and not 1800.

Comment: @yspreen afterwards minutes will be converted to seconds -- "if datetime.now() - last_touch > timedelta(0, auto_logout_time * 60, 0)"

Answer (score 8):

As of Django 1.4 (and later), you can also set the duration of a session by setting [`SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_COOKIE_AGE) in the settings file.

> `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`
>
> Default: 1209600 (2 weeks, in seconds)
>
> The age of session cookies, in seconds.